# Can't mount iso to virtual machine

Tags: repository, rpm

I want to set up a local repository to install rpm packets but i get this

```
# mount -o loop  -t iso9660 /dev/cdrom /media/cdrom
mount: /dev/sr0: failed to setup loop device: No medium found
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering the information provided:

1. The problem is in a VM
2. The error shows "No medium found"

Can you confirm that you `attached` the `CDROM` to the VM?

Some links which details about "attach external media to a VM"

- https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917924.aspx
- https://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_disk_add_cd_dvd.html